# Mask not fully masking

Tags: masking

So I made a mask of a clip then applied it to the same clip in the video editor but part of the mask is missing. Mask: [image: mask] Video: [image: vid]

Comment: Output? I never outputted and they are both the same vid

Comment: [Output option *Dimensions > Resolution*](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/output.html) affects some things in the workflow regardless whether something was already rendered or not. One of things which depend on that is masking. So do render resolution set in [Output options](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/output.html) and resolution of the video you loaded into the VSE match ?